# Projecting QGIS map into solid shapes

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I got a request to produce a world map that can be printed, cut, and assembled into a globe. I know there are ways to make fairly simple shapes, but the guy wants a geodetic sphere, which has 720 triangular surfaces. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How big is this globe going to be? There's little difference between a "geodetic sphere" and a bowling ball. All you need to do is make the paint a little bit thicker at the Equator.

Comment: I think it would be about 12-18 inches in diameter. Based on the person's request, it looks like the shape would be made up of 20 triangles, each subdivided into 38 smaller triangles. The 20 big triangles would be printed and cut apart, then glued together to form the completed shape.